# Nested If Statements PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

I have the following if statement which is working fine:

```
if ($user['email_only'] === '1') {
    $newsubscriber['subscriberMessage'] = array('masterId' => '1090438');
} else if($user['email_only'] === '0') {
    $newsubscriber['subscriberMessage'] = array('masterId' => '1090442');
}
```

However, I wanted to add an extra if statement around this so that I could have different id's set based upon the users country, I came up with the following, but it is not working?

```
if ($user['country'] === 'au') {
    if($user['email_only'] === '1') {
        $newsubscriber['subscriberMessage'] = array('masterId' => '1091479');
} else {
        $newsubscriber['subscriberMessage'] = array('masterId' => '1090589');
    }
} // AU country END 
else if ($user['country'] === 'de') {
    if($user['email_only'] === '1') {
        $newsubscriber['subscriberMessage'] = array('masterId' => '1090438');
    } else {
        $newsubscriber['subscriberMessage'] = array('masterId' => '1090442');
    }
} // DE country END
```

Can someone help me as to where I am going wrong?

Comment: Start by indenting your code the correct way. That makes a huge difference. By the way.. what is not working? Do you get any errors?

Comment: *It's not working* isn't very helpful. What should it be doing, what is it actually doing? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Are you sure that $user['country'] is a string?

Comment: Are you sure that `$user['email_only']` is `'1'` and not `1` or `true` ?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use *exactly equal* (`===`) unless you need to and are absolutely sure of the data you are getting. Try this:

```
if ($user['country'] == 'au') {
    if($user['email_only'] == '1') {
        $newsubscriber['subscriberMessage'] = array('masterId' => '1091479');
} else {
        $newsubscriber['subscriberMessage'] = array('masterId' => '1090589');
    }
} // AU country END 
else if ($user['country'] == 'de') {
    if($user['email_only'] == '1') {
        $newsubscriber['subscriberMessage'] = array('masterId' => '1090438');
    } else {
        $newsubscriber['subscriberMessage'] = array('masterId' => '1090442');
    }
} // DE country END
```

The other thing you can do is `var_dump($user);` to make sure you have the expected values in country and email_only that you are expecting.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, you should just format your code properly ... i wouldnt find mistakes in this mess either.

```
if ($user['country'] === 'au'){
    if ($user['email_only'] === 1) {
        $newsubscriber['subscriberMessage'] = array('masterId' => '1090438');
    }else if($user['email_only'] === 0){
        $newsubscriber['subscriberMessage'] = array('masterId' => '1090442');
    }//AU END
} else if ($user['country'] === 'de'){
    if ($user['email_only'] === 1) {
        $newsubscriber['subscriberMessage'] = array('masterId' => '1090438');
    }else if($user['email_only'] === 0){
        $newsubscriber['subscriberMessage'] = array('masterId' => '1090442');
    }
} //DE END
```

Comment: What is the difference apart from formatting it?

Comment: The difference is that i removed the quotes from the numbers because i dont think these actually are numbers.

Comment: Oh. Well. Thats what you get for using copy and paste without attention. Thx for that, gonna fix it.